# Compare two array item to skip

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two arrays (this is an JSON array from PHP)

one

```
"result1": [
    {
        "driverId": "3",
        "latitude": "23.752182",
        "longitude": "90.377730",
        "distance": "0.00011211999971692422",
        "EstTime": 137
    },
        {
        "driverId": "4",
        "latitude": "23.75182",
        "longitude": "90.3730",
        "distance": "0.000171692422",
        "EstTime": 111
    }
]
```

Two

```
"result2": [
    {
        "driverId": "3"
    }
]
```

I want to compare these arrays. if any result1 item driverID matches any item of result2 then skip that item from result1

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two stages.

First gather the `driverId`s to exclude using [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map)

```
$exclude    = array_map(
    function($v) {
        return $v['driverId'];
    },
    $json['result2']
);
```

Then use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/array_filter) to filter out those elements you do not want:

```
$result = array_filter(
    $json['result1'],
    function($a) use ($exclude) {
        return !in_array($a['driverId'], $exclude);
    }
);
```

I have tested this with the following code. If you have separate arrays, just supply them independently above instead of using `$json['result1']`.

```
    $a = <<<JSON
{
    "result1": [
    {
        "driverId": "3",
        "latitude": "23.752182",
        "longitude": "90.377730",
        "distance": "0.00011211999971692422",
        "EstTime": 137
    },
        {
        "driverId": "4",
        "latitude": "23.75182",
        "longitude": "90.3730",
        "distance": "0.000171692422",
        "EstTime": 111
    }
],
"result2": [
    {
        "driverId": "3"
    }
]
}
JSON;
    $json = json_decode($a, true);
```

Comment: Strange - this message is 19 minutes old? How did that happen? Anyway, since our answers are the same basically (yours has more detail) I'll delete mine :)

Comment: @Darragh, Iserni posted his answer first and deleted it and now he just undeleted it. You don't have to delete yours , Let me vote you up both because you both are correct.

Comment: Ah ha. I see :) Okay, that makes sense.. thanks, I undeleted mine - I think @Isemi's answer is more complete though.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. In this answer I am assuming that you have already applied `json_decode()` and extracted `$result1` and `$result2` into PHP arrays.

*Further to your last comment, code edited to work in version 5.2*

```
<?php

// associative array of result1
$result1 = array(
    array(
        'driverId'  => '3',
        'latitude'  => '23.752182',
        'longitude' => '90.377730',
        'distance'  => '0.00011211999971692422',
        'EstTime'   =>  137
    ),
    array(
        'driverId'  => '4',
        'latitude'  => '23.75182',
        'longitude' => '90.3730',
        'distance'  => '0.000171692422',
        'EstTime'   => 111
    )
);

// associative array of result2
$result2 = array(
    array(
        'driverId' =>  '3'
    )
);

// first, let's get a list of ids that we want to exclude
// run array map over the result2 and return the ids - this
// creates an array of "exclusion" ids. Note you could use
// foreach here also.

function pluckResultIds($result) {
    return $result['driverId'];
}

$excludeIds = array_map('pluckResultIds', $result2);

var_dump($excludeIds); // result: array(3)

// next let's use array_filter to run over result1. for each
// entry in result1 - we check if the current driverId is in
// the exclusion array - if it is *not* we return the current
// this creates a new array $filtered containing only the
// filtered elements that do not match

$filtered = array();
foreach ($result1 as $result) {
    $id = $result['driverId'];
    if (!in_array($id, $excludeIds)) {
        $filtered[] = $result;
    }
};

var_dump($filtered);
```

Yields:

```
array (size=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'driverId' => string '4' (length=1)
      'latitude' => string '23.75182' (length=8)
      'longitude' => string '90.3730' (length=7)
      'distance' => string '0.000171692422' (length=14)
      'EstTime' => int 111
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: As promised :)  .. +1

Comment: And I'm upvoting it because I hadn't checked before undeleting (I had deleted because my first version was incomplete and incorrect).

Comment: have error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

i store my result1 array in $info and result2 array in $infor

then write this code 

$excludeIds = array_map(function($result) {
    return $result['driverId'];
}, $infor);

$filtered = array_filter($info, function($result) use ($excludeIds) {
    $id = $result['driverId'];
    if (!in_array($id, $excludeIds)) {
        return $result;
    }
});

Comment: @user3503336 Ah.... you are getting that error because you are using a version of PHP less than 5.3. This specific error is because the version you are using does not support anonymous functions/closures. I assume you are on 5.2? Check with `<?php echo phpversion();`. The current stable version is 5.5 so you'll find most answers (like the two above) assume a certain minimum subset of functionality. I will edit my answer shortly to make the answer compatible with 5.2!

Comment: Updated. Working example here (choose PHP 5.2 from dropdown). http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac5454cdc62dea13ec72eca96bb4029e652131e8 - also you should get using at least 5.4 if you can. Lots of really good stuff in modern PHP!